# Few basic questions about sigma-field

Tags: probability-theory

As i learned in the class, the sigma-field F has the following properties:

1,sample space Ω belongs to F.

2,If A belongs to F, then $A^c$ belongs to F. F is closed under complements.

3, if $(A_k)_{k \in N}⊆ F$, then all the union of $A_k$ belongs to F, F is closed under countable union.

could someone explain what is the meaning of 'closed' here?  and also the A and $A_k$ here is an element or a set?

sorry I actually have more questions, but i must attend the class right now.

English is not my first language, hope you can understand what I wrote. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is *closed* under some operation if whenever we use that operation on elements of the set, we get again an element of the set. For example, the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ are closed under addition: whenever we add two natural numbers together, we get again a natural number. However, the natural numbers are *not* closed under subtraction: $1 - 2 = -1$, and $-1$ is not a natural number, even though both $1$ and $2$ were natural numbers.

So for $F$ to be closed under complement, means that whenever we have an element $A$ in $F$, if we take the complement of $A$, which we often write as $A^c$, then $A^c$ must also be in $F$.

Likewise, for $F$ to be closed under countable union means that whenever we take the union of a countable number of $A_k$'s from $F$, then that union must again be in $F$.

The elements $A$ of $F$ are sets, so you can think of them both as elements and sets. They are elements of $F$, but since $F$ is a set that contains sets, all the elements of $F$ are sets.

---

If we have a set $X$, then the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, X\}$ is known as the *trivial* $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let us verify that this is a $\sigma$-algebra:

1. Clearly, $X \in \Sigma$.
2. We have to check that the complement of $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\Sigma$. $\emptyset^c = X \in \Sigma$ and $X^c = \emptyset \in \Sigma$.
3. We have to check that any countable (possibly infinite, but always countable) union of elements of $\Sigma$ is again in $\Sigma$. However, $\Sigma$ only has finitely many elements, so we only need to check it for finite unions. In fact, there is only one union to check: $\emptyset \cup X = X \in \Sigma$.

If we have a set $B = [2,5]$ and define an attempted "$\sigma$-algebra" on $B$ as $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, [2,5], [2,3],\{4\}\}$, then we can see that this is in fact not a $\sigma$-algebra, because the complement of $\{4\}$ is an interval with a hole in it at $4$, namely $\{4\}^c = [2,5] \setminus \{4\}$. This "interval" is not an element of $\Sigma$, so it is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can understand your explanations. But I have two more questions. Hope you could explain them. 1) if a F is a sigma-field in set B={1,2,3,4} a smallest sigma-field F is { empty set,B}. Shall you show me how this example matches the properties 2) and 3)? I mean what is the A and Ak in this sigma-field.   2) a set B=[2,5], a set F ={ empty set, [2-5], [2-3], {4} } is not a sigma-field on B, why? And what can we add to F and let it be a sigma-field on B?    Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry, type wrong the [2-5] and [2-3] should be [2,5] and [2,3]

Comment: @Zabbkaosckey I have expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you mrp, for second answer, I don't understand {4}^c = [2,4) U (4,5] is not element of sigma? Why? [2,5] can cover both {4}^c and {4}.

Comment: @Zabbkaosckey Sure, but the definition does not say that there should be an element that *covers* $[2,4) \cup (4,5]$, it says that there should be an element that *is exactly* $[2,4) \cup (4,5]$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I Feel something's weird. Let's say another example. B={1,2,3}. Can I say { B, empty set, {1} } is not a sigma-fieldon B, cuz there is not {1}^c in the F?

Comment: @Zabbkaosckey Yes, but if you add $\{1\}^c = \{2,3\}$, then it becomes a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: Thank you very much Mrp, you enhance my understanding on sigma-field. For second question B=[2,5], what can we add to F so that it can be a sigma-field-field?  I think we need add a {4}^c , am I right?

Comment: @Zabbkaosckey Well, it's not as easy as that. Of course, you need to add $\{4\}^c$, but you also need to add $[2,3] \cup \{4\}$, and then you probably need to add the complement of that, and then you need to check that the set is still closed under complement and countable union with the newly added elements, and so on...

Comment: ...so complicated, anyway, thank you kindly help.

Comment: @Zabbkaosckey If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: sorry, I dont get you point, what did your mean check mark? Actualy I have more questions want to ask you, but I dont want to expand to much space in this page.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is closed under complements, it means that if $A \in F$, than also $A^C \in F$.
The same when $F$ is closed under countable union, that means $A_k \in F$, then $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k \in F$.

And if $A \in F$ is a element or set, depends on how you look at it. In the context of $F$, $A$ is an element of the set $F$. However, if we look at $A$ in context of $\Omega$, we have that $A$ is a subset of $\Omega$.
This is because $F$ is a subset of the powerset of $\Omega$.